# How do I hide an <i> tag if the <a> tag is empty

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I want to hide the second phone `<i>` tag if the `<a>` tag is empty. The phone numbers are going to be pulled in from a Google Sheet using SheetDB and displayed with PODS short codes.

Here is the code:

```
    <p>Get my free no-obligation quote today: <span><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="tel:<?php echo do_shortcode('[pods name="wpwc_replace_fields" slug="51" field="phone_number"]'); ?>"> <?php echo do_shortcode('[pods name="wpwc_replace_fields" slug="51" field="phone_number"]'); ?></a></span><br />
    <span><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="tel:<?php echo do_shortcode('[pods name="wpwc_replace_fields" slug="142" field="phone_number_2"]'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[pods name="wpwc_replace_fields" slug="142" field="phone_number_2"]'); ?></a></span></p>
```

I don't know if this can be done simply with CSS, or more likely javascript, but any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: you can move `i` into `<a>` tag

Comment: Then `if (!whatever condition you need to use to check if a is empty) { output i }`, otherwise you do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress, this is usually done with php.

Try replacing your code with:

```
    <?php
        $first_phone_number = do_shortcode('[pods name="wpwc_replace_fields" slug="51" field="phone_number"]');
        $second_phone_number = do_shortcode('[pods name="wpwc_replace_fields" slug="142" field="phone_number_2"]');
    ?>
    
    <p>Get my free no-obligation quote today: <span><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="tel:<?php echo $first_phone_number; ?>"> <?php echo $first_phone_number; ?></a></span><br />

    <?php if ($second_phone_number): ?>
        <span><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="tel:<?php echo $second_phone_number; ?>"><?php echo $second_phone_number; ?></a></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
```

Using variables you will also save server resources by not calling *do_shortcode()* twice for each phone number :)

Comment: Thanks @Hillel, that has worked to a degree, although in the PODS custom field, I have to have the placeholder for phone number 2, {{phone2}}, so it can be replaced with the data from the Google sheet, so if thats filled in, the `<i>` tag still displays. Can it be drilled down further, say when the `<a>` tag starts with a 0, show the `<i>`, if not, hide it?

Comment: Sure you can, but if I understand you correctly you have a field in the back-end with a constant value '{{phone2}}' that is getting replaced on the front-end by data taken from Google Sheets? If that is the case you will either need a front-end solution, or back-end Google integration. Please clarify

Comment: Yes, that's right, whatever is entered in the Google sheet field is replacing the relevant placeholder. What would you suggest?

Comment: Assuming that you have little or no control over the FE replacement, I would try a pure CSS approach - there is a CSS selector for empty elements - :empty (see here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

For this to work you'll need to make a small adjustment to the way you use Font Awesome - instead of the <i> element method, use the ::before method (see here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements).

That way you'll be able to hide the FA icons pseudo-elements using the :empty selector when there is no data from Google Sheets.